# WCF receive timeout

Tags: wcf

When attempting to connect/communicate with my service i have to wait for almost exactly 20 seconds each time before the exception is fired. Since this all gonna be running on a local network, I would like decrease that timeout period to 5 seconds? I tried decreasing the receiveTimeout on my client, but it didn't work. I looked all over my code for a 20 second timeout variable set, but couldn't find any. What should i be changing?

Answer (score 2):

There are different timeout settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx. They can be set for example in a config file (web.config or app.config) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx as an example. Under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731399.aspx you can choose the binding which you use and set the corresponding setting.

**UPDATED**: You probably have the timeout set on the TCP level. Try reducing the `TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions` (Default value 2) or  `TcpInitialRTT` (Default value 3, on NT 4.0 the parameter has the name `InitialRTT`) parameters in the registry, reboot your computer and try your experiments one more time. About affect of 21 seconds you can read in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223450, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175523, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170359 or http://www.boyce.us/windows/tipcontent.asp?ID=189. You can read a description of the TCP/IP default configuration values at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314053 (for Windows XP) and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739819(WS.10).aspx (for Windows Server 2003 with SP2).

Comment: currently the code in my client app.config looks like this:
closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
These settings as is, make me wait for aprox. 20 seconds before receiving a EndpointNotFoundException, when the service is down. Which setting am i supposed to make that go down to 5 seconds?

Comment: you can use Microsoft Network Monitor (see  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=103158&clcid=0x409) to capture,  view and analyze network traffic. I suppose you have problem on the TCP level (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

What you may actually be seeing is the cold start from your webapp.  The Service Not Found exception would fire back pretty quickly unelss you had hit it pretty hard and you started queueing service requests beyond what WCF was configured to do.

However, if you had your website unloaded (appdomain and worker process) it could take 20 seconds to hit to the code that builds the channel to your service.  So it may be something masked.

If your website and service are in different application pools then this is maginfied because it has to cold start the website and then coldstart the service, which are done in succession instead of simultaneously.

To somewhat alleviate this you can use a keepalive/ping service.  Something that just constantly hits the URL to keep the AppDomain in memory and the worker process alive (if not shared).  By default IIS 6 will shutdown the worker process after 20 minutes of inactivity, so when the first request comes in, http.sys starts up a new worker process, which loads the framework, which loads your app, which starts the pipeline, which executes your code, which delivers to your user. :)